# Monotonicity of softmax (considering updates from all variables)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, derivative, softmax, jacobian

There's a relevant question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535120/how-to-prove-the-monotonicity-of-softmax-when-decreasing-the-weighted-inputs) that doesn't quite answer my question, but I'm unable to comment.

Define softmax to be $$a_i = \text{softmax}(u_i)= \frac{e^{u_i}}{\sum_j{e^{u_j}}}$$
As the linked post shows, if $u_i$ increases, it will always cause $a_i$ to increase and will push all other $a_j$ down because $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial u_j} \geq 0$ when $i=j$ and $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial u_j} \leq 0$ when $i\neq j$. In other words, the Jacobian is nonnegative along the diagonal and nonpositive in the off-diagonals, and can be written as
$$J = \frac{\text{diag}(e^{u_i}\sum_j{e^{u_j}}) - e^{u_i} e^{u_j}}{(\sum_j e^{u_j})^2} = \begin{bmatrix} a_0-a_0a_0 & -a_0a_1 & \dots &  -a_0a_N \\ -a_1a_0 & a_1-a_1a_1 & \dots & -a_1a_N \\ & \vdots & \\ a_N-a_Na_0 & \dots & \dots & a_N -a_Na_N \end{bmatrix} $$

My question: **When $u_i$ increases, does $a_i$ always increase, taking into account updates from changes to all other $u_j$, $j\neq i$?** For example, is it possible that $u_i$ and some $u_j$ could both increase, but that $u_j$ increases more and pushes $a_i$ down (in addition to some other increasing $u_j$s pushing $a_i$ down slightly) such that $a_i$ decreases overall? In other words, for each row of $J$, is it possible that the magnitude of the sum of the off-diagonal nonpositive updates exceeds the magnitude of the nonnegative update?

I think I could show this by proving that $J$ is positive semidefinite (we know it is symmetric) but I'm not sure how to do this.